# FindMinimum(vectorized): Stepmonitor doesn't work

Tags: mathematical-optimization, monitoring

In the documentation I found this simple example which evaluates as expected:

```
R1 = Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}];
R2 = Disk[{2, 2}, 1];
FindMinimum[{EuclideanDistance[x, y], {x \[Element] R1,y \[Element] R2}}, {x, y}, Method-> {  "InteriorPoint" }] 
(*{1.12132, {x -> {0.5, 0.5}, y -> {1.29289, 1.29289}}}*)
```

The variables are lists defined implicit !

If I try `Stepmonitor` Mathematica fails to show the correct values

```
Reap[FindMinimum[{EuclideanDistance[x, y], {x \[Element] R1,y \[Element] R2}}, {x, y} 
, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[Evaluate[{x, y}]]    ,Method -> {  "InteriorPoint" }]]
```

I get

```
(*{{1.12132, {x -> {0.5, 0.5},y -> {1.29289, 1.29289}}}, 
{{{x, y}, {x, y}, {x, y}, {x, y}, {x,y}, {x, y}, {x, y}, {x, y}, {x, y}, {x, y}, {x, y},{x, y}, {x, y}, {x, y}, {x, y}, {x, y}, {x, y}
,...*)
```

The steps `x,y` aren't displayed.

What's wrong here? Thanks!